# Get all last members in a SQL Server hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, hierarchyid

I am trying to find all first items of the last hierarchy members ("leafs") in a SQL Server hierarchy. I was able to find similar questions, however solutions with `GetAncestors` don't work with our SQL Server version.

I was able to use this solution:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(20), MasterOrder) AS HierarchyString 
FROM 
    TestTable2 PARENT
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM TestTable2 CHILD
                WHERE CHILD.Id <> PARENT.Id 
                  AND CHILD.MasterOrder.IsDescendantOf(PARENT.MasterOrder) = 1)
```

This returns the correct results, but for some reason only 12 out of 25 rows. I think too many rows are included in the `NOT EXISTS` range, but I don't have experience with `CHILD` and `PARENT` keywords and interestingly enough, failed to find MS documentation for them.

EDIT: *I couldn't find it, because I was very tired and somehow didn't noticed those are aliases, not keywords :-)*

Here is data with marked rows (`<<<`), that the query should return.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable2
(
     RowNo       INT NOT NULL, 
     ID          INT NOT NULL, 
     MasterOrder HierarchyID NOT NULL,
     SeqNo       INT NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845192, '/', 1);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (3, 845196, '/1/', 3);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845194, '/1/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845193, '/1/', 1);      -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845238, '/10/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845239, '/10/', 1);     -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845242, '/11/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845241, '/11/', 1);     -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (3, 845245, '/12/', 3);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845244, '/12/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845243, '/12/', 1);     -- No! ...has children.
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845246, '/12/1/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845264, '/12/10/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845263, '/12/10/', 1);  -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845247, '/12/2/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845249, '/12/3/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845251, '/12/4/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845252, '/12/5/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845254, '/12/6/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845257, '/12/7/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845256, '/12/7/', 1);   -- <<< 
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845260, '/12/8/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845261, '/12/8/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845262, '/12/9/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (3, 845267, '/13/', 3);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845268, '/13/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845266, '/13/', 1);     -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (3, 845272, '/14/', 3);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845271, '/14/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845269, '/14/', 1);     -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (3, 845276, '/15/', 3);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845275, '/15/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845273, '/15/', 1);     -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845278, '/16/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845277, '/16/', 1);     -- No! ...has children.
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845279, '/16/1/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845296, '/16/10/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845297, '/16/10/', 1);  -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845299, '/16/11/', 1);  -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845301, '/16/12/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845302, '/16/12/', 1);  -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845304, '/16/13/', 1);  -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (3, 845309, '/16/14/', 3);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845308, '/16/14/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845306, '/16/14/', 1);  -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (3, 845313, '/16/15/', 3);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (2, 845312, '/16/15/', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845310, '/16/15/', 1);  -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845281, '/16/2/', 1);   -- <<<
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (RowNo, ID, MasterOrder, SeqNo) VALUES (1, 845282, '/16/3/', 1);   -- <<<
```

The `RowNo` column is originally a `ROW_NUMBER` column I added, it gives order number for the same hierarchy items (with identical hierarchy string). It has always one "1" for each leaf, even if the original sequence number starts i.e. with 3 (because 1 and 2 are excluded due to their state).

So the task is to get all the "leafs" with `RowNo = 1`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, analyzing it in detail I found the problem is apparently in the fact, that `IsDescendantOf()` is considering 3 different rows with same hierarchy value i.e. `/13/` to be **descendants** of each other. My understanding of descendant was that it's a "child", especially because that is what documentation seems to state:

> Returns true for all the nodes in the sub-tree rooted at parent, and false for all other nodes.

But as per my tests, it returns *siblings* too.

Once the problem was understood, it was easy to fix the code to get proper 25 rows:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(20), MasterOrder) AS HierarchyString 
FROM 
    TestTable2 as PARENT
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM TestTable2 as CHILD
                WHERE RowNo = 1   -- <<< New condition <<<
                  AND CHILD.Id <> PARENT.Id 
                  AND CHILD.MasterOrder.IsDescendantOf(PARENT.MasterOrder) = 1)
                  ;
```

Adding `RowNo = 1` into the selection of items to be excluded is ensuring that `IsDescendantOf` is performed only on those rows, so there are no siblings to play "false" childred.